# Finding the probability that a male line continues forever.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Suppose that every man in a certain society has exactly three
> children, which independently have probability one-half of being a boy
> and one-half of being a girl. Suppose also that the number of males in
> the n th generation forms a branching process. 
> (a) Find the probability that the male line of a given man eventually becomes
> extinct. 
> (b) If a given man has two boys and one girl, what is the
> probability that his male line will continue forever?

Attempt:
For part a, we could calculate the extinction probability by letting $$f(x) = x \implies \frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}x+\frac{3}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{8}x^3 = x$$
and solving for $x$ and taking the smaller root.
I am not sure, what I need to do for part b? Some guidance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The probability of a man's male line becoming extinct is equal to the probability of all of his (exactly three) heirs' male lines becoming extinct.  (Female children have immediately extinct male lines.)  Since those events are i.i.d., it's the case that
$$
p_e=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}p_e\right)^3=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}p_e+\frac{3}{8}p_e^2+\frac{1}{8}p_e^3,
$$
as OP states.  Equivalently,
$$
(p_e - 1)(p_e^2 + 4p_e - 1) = 0.
$$
One solution is $p_e=1$.  If $p_e \neq 1$, then the other positive solution is $p_e = \sqrt{5}-2 \approx 0.2361.$  Part (b) asks for the survival probability given exactly two male heirs: this is then $1-p_e^2=4\sqrt{5}-8\approx 0.9443.$

Comment: I am questioning the correctness of this. There is more than one solution [solving for $p_e$] to the equation $p_e = \Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{p_e}{2}\Big)^3$; $p_e$ in the interval $[0,1]$; though.  Why is $p_e=1$ the solution then?

Comment: In fact, by this reasoning, $p_e=1$ if a male has $k$ children, for a general nonnegative integer $k$, a male's line should still die out with probability $p_e=1$, as $p_e=1$ is a solution to $p_e = \Big(1+\frac{p_e}{2}\Big)^k$. Yes, $p_e=1$ is the solution for $k=0$ [obviously] and $k=1$, and I think $k=2$. But I don't think $p_e$ is $1$ for $k \ge 3$. As a male expects to have $\frac{k}{2}$ male children and $\frac{k}{2} > 1$ for all $k \ge 3$, with positive probability the number of male offspring he should have should increase exponentially i.e., no extinction.

Comment: We were told if the expected value is greater than 1, we solve the equation and take the smallest root. For that quadratic, The other root is approximately 0.7143, so I think we should take that as the answer for part a.

Comment: @Oran, if you have the two roots of $1$ and $0.7143$, how do you know which root is appropriate?

Comment: We were just told to take the smaller root. I do not understand why that is the case, and will ask my prof during office hours later.